# How to hide extensions in apache without .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.4

I want to hide the .php extension on my apache server but within a Directory section since .htaccess will slow down the server.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem specification.** I *suppose* you would like to hide the exact [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) ([URN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name), specifically).
So, instead of making a request to http://example.com/contact.php, you would prefer to request: http://example.com/contact.

**Answer.** There are various ways of achieving that:

- **Option 1.** You can make a rewrite by enabling [**`mod_rewrite`**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module and configuring `Directory` *VritualHost* accordingly.

```
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php
```

- **Option 2.** You can add a set of directories and put `index.php` there.

```
var/www/html ⇣47% ≫ tree .
.
├── blah
│   └── index.php
└── contact
    └── index.php

2 directories, 2 files

var/www/html ⇣47% ≫
```

Remember about application routing, in general it is a way better way to manage manage routing dynamically.

Comment: Should I specify a RewriteRule for each page?

Comment: No, the documentation says that RewriteRule can be written at Server context level and it does not has be related to VHost. (But, I would say VHost our Directory configurations are the most common place for a rule).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `.htaccess`. Most things written for `.htaccess` files may work in `.conf`.

You'd use the [mod_rewrite code to remove the extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15940822/12989672), and have it be in one of your .conf files, such as `apache2.conf`, `httpd.conf`, or `site-available/*.conf`.